# Matching Org Headlines against a Property Function?

Tags: org-mode

How can I use elisp to search for headlines that return true against a predicate function? In particular, I already have an elisp function `within-intervalp` which checks whether a number `num` is within the range specified by property `:INTERVAL:` (at point). So for example if I have

```
* Parent
** Child1
:PROPERTIES:
:INTERVAL: [2,3]
:END:
*** Subchild1
:PROPERTIES:
:INTERVAL: [2,4]
:END:
** Child2
:PROPERTIES:
:INTERVAL: [5,7]
:END:
** Child3
:PROPERTIES:
:INTERVAL: [7,9]
:END:
```

and I run `(within-intervalp 2.5)`, I'd like to see `Child1` and `Subchild1` pop up in a search. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use org-element-map to collect headlines that meet some criteria.

Something like this:

```
 (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
         (lambda (hl)
           (goto-char (org-element-property :begin hl))
           (when (within-intervalp 2.5)
         hl)))
```

should return a list of headlines meeting your criteria. You can then map over the list to return candidates for ivy/helm or some other selection engine.